# Android : Tween animation: Moving an ImageView

Tags: android, animation, tween

I have a problem with tween animation in android , I try to move an `ImageView` item from center of screen to top of screen but after end of transform `ImageView` returns to first position! I use this code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <translate 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"
         android:fromYDelta="0%"
         android:toYDelta="-1500%"
         android:duration="3000"
         android:startOffset="3000">
         </translate>

private void RunAnimations() {

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move_up_maxname);
    animation.reset();
    ImageView maxName = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    maxName.clearAnimation();
    maxName.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a look at setFillAfter:

> If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.

Answer (score 2):

Use [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) and in onAnimationEnd() change the position of ImageView(Last point).

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

   public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim)
   {};

   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim)
   {};

   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim)
   {
     //Change imageview position using LayoutParameters
   };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

add line 
   animation.setFillAfter(true);